# Angular project compilation error with module lodash

Tags: node.js, angularjs, typescript, lodash

I've a external project which I'm trying to run on my local machine, the package.js is:

```js
{
    "name": "default",
    "version": "0.5.4",
    "license": "MIT",
    "browserslist": [
        "last 1 version",
        "> 1%"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "build-local": "ng build --configuration local",
        "build-staging": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration staging",
        "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
        "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
        "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^0.10.3",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.2.0",
        "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^2.1.1",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.6.0",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
        "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "^2.5.7",
        "fast-deep-equal": "^3.1.1",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
        "ng-click-outside": "^5.1.1",
        "ng-mat-select-infinite-scroll": "^2.0.0",
        "ng-pick-datetime": "^6.0.16",
        "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
        "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
        "ngx-auth": "4.0.0",
        "ngx-highlightjs": "^2.0.4",
        "ngx-mask": "6.5.18",
        "ngx-mat-daterange-picker": "^1.1.4",
        "ngx-mat-select-search": "^1.7.2",
        "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^6.2.0",
        "ngx-permissions": "^5.0.0",
        "ngx-smart-popover": "1.0.0",
        "ngx-spinner": "^6.1.2",
        "object-path": "^0.11.4",
        "rxjs": "6.4.0",
        "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.5",
        "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.7.0",
        "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
        "@angular/material": "^6.4.0",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^6.4.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^10.5.2",
        "codelyzer": "^4.4.2",
        "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
        "jasmine-core": "^3.1.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~2.0.4",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.2.0",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "prettier": "^2.0.5",
        "protractor": "^5.3.2",
        "ts-node": "^6.0.3",
        "tslint": "~5.9.1",
        "typescript": "2.8"
    }
}
```

I've been told that this project uses Node.js 12.22.1 so I've installed it, npm version coming with this version is 6.14.12, after run npm install I only get some warnings, so I tried to run npm run start and I get the following errors:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(176,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(186,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(227,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(237,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(732,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(742,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(784,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(794,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(1782,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(1788,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(1809,86): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(1813,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(1819,86): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/array.d.ts(1823,71): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts(12,20): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts(21,20): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts(97,21): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts(190,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts(200,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts(212,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts(234,132): error TS2344: Type 'K' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
  Type 'PropertyKey' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts(255,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/common.d.ts(256,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(35,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(41,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(297,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(309,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(333,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(345,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(381,10): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(381,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(418,29): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(420,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(429,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(500,25): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(502,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(508,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(532,25): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(532,68): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(532,77): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(536,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(542,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(556,45): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(556,71): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(558,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(562,29): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(562,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(564,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(568,34): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(568,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(578,25): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(580,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(586,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(603,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(609,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(650,38): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(650,57): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(651,50): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(651,79): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(652,62): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(652,97): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(653,74): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(653,117): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(654,86): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(654,137): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(657,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(744,56): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(744,87): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(751,48): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(751,79): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(758,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(758,71): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(765,32): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(765,63): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(773,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(860,56): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(860,87): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(867,48): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(867,79): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(874,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(874,71): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(881,32): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(881,63): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(934,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1091,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1091,72): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1097,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1254,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1254,77): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1271,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1277,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1296,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1302,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1320,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1326,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1359,29): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1361,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1370,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1394,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1398,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1400,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/function.d.ts(1404,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/lang.d.ts(33,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/lang.d.ts(69,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1894,13): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2078,117): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2098,122): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2306,52): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(2330,52): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/seq.d.ts(65,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/seq.d.ts(95,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/seq.d.ts(101,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(175,64): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(175,199): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(179,64): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(179,238): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(183,60): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(183,176): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(187,56): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(187,153): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(191,52): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(191,130): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(195,48): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(195,107): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(199,44): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(199,84): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(205,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(209,174): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(209,183): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(213,213): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(213,222): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(217,151): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(217,160): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(221,128): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(221,137): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(225,105): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(225,114): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(229,82): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(229,91): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(233,59): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(233,68): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(243,179): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(243,188): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(247,218): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(247,227): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(251,156): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(251,165): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(255,133): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(255,142): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(259,110): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(259,119): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(263,87): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(263,96): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(267,64): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(267,73): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(282,183): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(282,204): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(286,160): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(286,181): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(290,137): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(290,158): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(294,114): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(294,135): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(298,91): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(298,112): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(302,68): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(302,89): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(312,71): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(312,172): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(312,202): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(316,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(316,149): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(316,179): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(320,63): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(320,126): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(320,156): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(324,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(324,103): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(324,133): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(328,55): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(328,80): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(328,110): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(332,41): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(332,56): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(332,87): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(342,71): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(342,172): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(342,207): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(346,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(346,149): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(346,184): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(350,63): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(350,126): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(350,161): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(354,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(354,103): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(354,138): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(358,55): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(358,80): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(358,115): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(362,41): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(362,56): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(362,92): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(429,35): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(453,40): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(755,60): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(771,95): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(771,104): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(783,100): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(783,109): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(794,59): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(810,94): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(810,103): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(822,99): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/util.d.ts(822,108): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parameters'.

ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Above output is using the last versions of lodash and types/lodash packages, on lodash repository on Github I did not find any info about this specific errors. Any help is welcome!!!